# querySelector works but querySelectorAll does not

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am trying to change the color of the anchor tags on scroll, as well as the background color of the navbar (which works). So far, using querySelector to select the first anchor tag seems to work but the querySelectorAll does not. I have tried to write a loop to iterate through all the anchor tags but I can't seem to figure out why it's not working :( If it helps, this is for a Wordpress site and it might be because the nodes are not static (according to my google research) but I thought the loop would resolve this. Any insight is much appreciated! Thank you :)

```
var nav = document.getElementById('site-navigation');
var link = document.querySelector('.menu-link')[0]; 

  for (i = 0; i < 0; i++){
      link[i].style.color= "blue";
  }

  window.onscroll = function() {
      if (window.pageYOffset > 100) {
          nav.style.background = "#406681"; 
          link.style.color = "#fff";


      }
      else {
          nav.style.background = "transparent";
          link.style.color = "blue";

      }
  }
```

Comment: Describe "does not work". What is the value of the `querySelector` expression, and what is the value of the `querySelectorAll` expression?

Comment: `querySelector()` returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector. And then why using `querySelector('.menu-link')[0]` ? And then you are using a loop to iterate one time?

Comment: Sorry that is a typo 
**bold**
`var link = document.querySelector('.menu-link');`

does in fact return the first element within the document, which is what I mean by 'it works'. If I change the variable to:
**bold**
`var link = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-link')[0]; `

nothing happens - which is what I meant by 'doesn't work'. I believe I have to loop through the anchors for the querySelectorAll to work but I'm not sure if the syntax is correct or if going about it this way is right at all. Apologies for the confusion!

Comment: @mbojko it is the same for both, the anchor tag with a class of .menu-link.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop never runs

`document.querySelector` returns the first element that satisfies the query given if there is none, i believe its either null or undefined

`document.querySelectorAll` returns a nodelist of elements that satisfies the query, if there is no elements in an empty node list

I'm assuming you want to make every link instead of just the first one, in which case,
are the links under nav? If so you can just add a class to nav depending on the scroll.

```
const nav = document.getElementById('site-navigation');
window.onscroll = function () {
    const navHasClass = nav.classList.contains("over-hundred");
    if (window.pageYOffset > 100) {
        if (!navHasClass) nav.classList.add("over-hundred");
    } else if (navHasClass) {
        nav.classList.remove("over-hundred");
    }
}
```

and in your css

```css
#site-navigation {
    background: #406681;
}

#site-navigation .menu-link {
    color: #fff;
}

#site-navigation.over-hundred {
    background: transparent;
}

#site-navigation.over-hundred .menu-link{
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works like a charm! I would have never been able to think of this solution - I really appreciate your explanation as well, thank you thank you thank you!